# How to get value and keys from an multidimenssional array?

Tags: arrays

I am using a foreach loop to get the values of an multidimenssional array. Loop is as follows:

```
foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
  print_r($v);
}
```

Output of this loop is as follows:

```
Array
(
  [1] => task1admin
  [status] => 0
)
Array
(
  [50] =>  task2pltfrom
  [status] => 0
)
```

I just want to store keys `[1]`,`[50]` in a variable also want to store values of key `[1]=>` its value and `[50]=>` its value.

Moreover, i also want to get `'status'` values.

I am new and confused with multidimensional array. Thanx a ton in advance.

Comment: ok, to get a quick answer - show how should look the final result

Comment: i want to store keys '[1]' and '[50]' as uid, and 'task1admin' , 'task2pltfrom' as activity and values '0' as status.

Comment: I used loop as
foreach ($v as $ky => $vl) {
  print_r($vl);
} 
and gives result as:
task1admin0 task2pltfrom0

How to get values out of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `key` and `current` functions:

```
$arr = [
    Array( 1 => 'task1admin', 'status' => 0 ),
    Array( 50 => 'task2pltfrom', 'status' => 0 )
];

// base structure
$result = ['uid' => [], 'activity' => [], 'status' => []];
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $result['status'][] = $v['status'];
    $result['uid'][] = key($v);
    $result['activity'][] = current($v);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [uid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 50
        )

    [activity] => Array
        (
            [0] => task1admin
            [1] => task2pltfrom
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: Now how store these values into variables ?

Comment: @Rajan, again, it's unclear what you are asking. Each variable should contain a separate value or an array of values? Show how should look that variables

Comment: how to store values in variable ?? Like say i want to store value "task1admin" in a variable then how to do it ?

Comment: so, use `$result` array from my answer and get the needed value into your variable, like `$activity1 = $result['activity'][0];`

Comment: can we use loop to get values dynamically ??

Answer (score 0):

Use predefined functions.

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and 
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: kindly explain more how to do it to get above mentioned results. I just started php and not know more about functions as well.

Comment: for getting all keys of array, $keys = array_keys($value); and for getting all values of array, $val = array_values($value);

Comment: It gives me result like this:
Array
(
    [0] => task1admin
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] =>  task2pltfrom
    [1] => 0
)
Its again array how i get values then ??